# Check if the next row to be added will be larger than a TablePanelLayout control's height

Tags: c#, winforms

In a WinForm application using a TablePanelLayout control I want to add rows until I've filled up the control. Since all rows are the same height it suffices to know the height of the last row added so far and it's location in the control.

To get the row height I can use RowStyles[lastRowNum]. But I don't see how to get the row's location. Alternatively, if I knew the largest y value of the last paint operation, that would also do. Finally, I could save the initial height of the TablePanelLayout control, set the control's height to zero and set AutoSize to true; then each new row would increase the size and I could check that. This seems possible but awkward. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried counting the number of controls you've added? if you know  the row height that should give you an accurate answer

Comment: That might work ... Unless the TablePanelLayout adds space between rows. I'll try and see.

Comment: I wound up using a WrapPanel. If not wrapped, each item in the panel will have the Y location of the panel. If any differ, it's wrapped.